# why is my code not working after wordpress update?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sms, code-snippets

I'm new here.
My Code is not working after wordpress update. Please guide me.
This code I have written after a long effort. Even though I don't have much knowledge about Coding. It was just working fine. But out of no where it is not working now. This actually sends an sms to admin when order is placed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'adminsms');
function adminsms( $order_id ){

    // Order Setup Via WooCommerce
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $orderid = get_post_meta($order_id, '_order_number', true);
    
    $odd = get_post_meta($order_id, '_id', true);
    $orderdd = get_post_meta($order_id, '_order_id', true);
    $billing_firstname = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_first_name', true);
    $billing_lastname = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_last_name', true);
    $billing_phone = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_phone', true);
    $shipping_address1 = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_1', true);
    $shipping_address2 = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_address_2', true);
    $city = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_city', true);
    $medallion = strtoupper(get_user_meta($order->user_id, 'loyalty_status', true));
    $order_amount = get_post_meta($order_id, '_order_total', true);
    $pay_type = get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true);
    
    $num1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $billing_phone );
    $num2 = ltrim($num1, "0");
    $num3 = str_replace('+9203', '923', $num2);
    $number = str_replace('+923', '923', $num3);

    //YOUR CREDENTIALS
    $sender = "awra";
    $username = "****";///Your Username
    $password = "****";///Your Password
    $mobile = "$number";///Recepient Mobile Number


    //YOUR MESSAGE to ADMIN
    $wa1 = "$billing_firstname%20$billing_lastname%20I%20have%20recieved%20your%20order%23%20$order_id%20of%20amount%20Rs.%20$order_amount.";
    $wamsg = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9%\-]/', '', $wa1);
    $alert = "$billing_firstname $billing_lastname
Order# $order_id
Amount: Rs. $order_amount
City: $city
wa.me/$billing_phone?text=$wamsg";
$url = 'http://api.muxmarketo.com/api/sendsms?id='.urlencode($username).'&pass='.urlencode($password).'&mobile='.urlencode(923234442972).'&brandname='.urlencode($sender).'&msg='.urlencode($alert).'&language=English';    
    
    
    

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}
else
{
    echo $output;
}
curl_close($ch); 
}
```

Comment: If that's your actual username and password, you're going to want to change it immediately...

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you